# AWS ELB ASP .NET MVC WEB API not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, amazon-elb

Everything works fine when I deploy the project using Single Instance configuration. But when I configure it to use Auto Scaling the web page doesn't work and I can only access the IIS default page.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I already solve it. In case it helps anybody this is what I did:

1. Check the EC2 instance, configure it's security group to access directly and check any endpoint that should be working.
2. If everything is ok with the code, you should see the endpoint working.
3. In the Beanstalk section, in your application configure the Health to point to that endpoint.
4. Do the same inside in Network Tier > Load Balancing.
5. Wait a couple of minutes and it should be working know.